# ¿Como recorrer un array anidado?

Tags: php

Pues me gustaría recorrer el array con foreach pero el problema es que al hacerlo me salta los siguientes errrores:

Notice: Undefined index: o in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Tarea 8. Recorrer un array anidado\recorrer array.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: t in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Tarea 8. Recorrer un array anidado\recorrer array.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: treintaycinco in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Tarea 8. Recorrer un array anidado\recorrer array.php on line 24

Ya llevo varios intentos de reescribir el código entero y aun así no cambia, este es mi código:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'o'=>array( 'otro','oso','ocio' ),
    't'=>array( 'te','tomate','tina',
'treintaycinco'=>array(
array('treinta', 'cinco'),
array('vingt', 'trois', array( 
'rojo' => 'varon',
'azul' => 'sangre'))
)
)
);


foreach($data as $valor) {

echo $valor['o']. '<br />';
echo $valor['t']. '<br />';
echo $valor['treintaycinco']. '<br />';
echo $valor['rojo']. '<br />';
echo $valor['azul']. '<br />';



}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sospechando que te trae algo complejo entre manos, considero que usar iteradores podría serte útil.

Veamos un ejemplo donde podremos recorrer un array muy complejo, por más anidado que esté:

```
$mIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($data),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($mIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key: \n";
    } else {
        echo "\t\t\t$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
o: 
            0 => otro
            1 => oso
            2 => ocio
t: 
            0 => te
            1 => tomate
            2 => tina
treintaycinco: 
0: 
            0 => treinta
            1 => cinco
1: 
            0 => vingt
            1 => trois
2: 
            rojo => varon
            azul => sangre
```

---

### Recomendaciones

- Los iteradores son herramientas potentes, no los uses para código banal, como leer un array simple o anidado en unos pocos niveles.
- Para conocer más sobre ellos, consulta el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/spl.iterators.php). Hay muchos tipos de iteradores como podrás verificar allí.
- Aquí hemos usado un [iterador recursivo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), porque interesaba moverse dentro de un array anidado en varios niveles con facilidad.
- Si estás interesado en desarrollo moderno de PHP puedes consultar algunas guías sobre iteradores, por ejemplo [esta](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/modern-php-developer-iterator), o bien [esta](https://webmobtuts.com/backend-development/php-iterators-part-1-traversable-iterable-iterator-and-iterator-aggregate/).

Answer (score 0):

El bucle que estás haciendo recorrería solamente el primer nivel de tu **array**, pero resulta que tenemos 5 niveles. Tendrías que hacer un bucle por cada nivel del **array** preguntando si el valor que se itera es un **array** o no para saber si pintarlo o profundizar un nivel más.

Esta manera tiene un inconveniente, ya que de tener un array de 6 niveles no funcionaría, teniendo que modificar el código para añadir un `foreach()` más. Es por eso por lo que se suele recurrir a la **recursividad** para este tipo de problemas.

No obstante me parece más aclarativo que veas esta manera de hacerse.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'o'=>array( 'otro','oso','ocio' ),
    't'=>array( 'te','tomate','tina', 'treintaycinco'=> array (
        array('treinta', 'cinco'),
        array('vingt', 'trois', array ( 
            'rojo' => 'varon',
            'azul' => 'sangre'))
        )
    )   
);


foreach($data as $nivel1) {
    if (is_array($nivel1)) {
        foreach ($nivel1 as $nivel2) {
            if (is_array($nivel2)) {
                foreach ($nivel2 as $nivel3) {
                    if (is_array($nivel3)) {
                        foreach ($nivel3 as $nivel4) {
                            if (is_array($nivel4)) {
                                foreach ($nivel4 as $nivel5) {
                                    if (is_array($nivel5)) {
                                        //No tenemos un sexto nivel de profundidad
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo 'Nivel 5: ';
                                        echo $nivel5 . '<br>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo 'Nivel 4: ';
                                echo $nivel4 . '<br>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'Nivel 3: ';
                        echo $nivel3 . '<br>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Nivel 2: ';
                echo $nivel2 . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Nivel 1: ';
        echo $nivel1 . '<br>';  
    }
}

?>
```

**Salida por pantalla**

```
Nivel 2: otro
Nivel 2: oso
Nivel 2: ocio
Nivel 2: te
Nivel 2: tomate
Nivel 2: tina
Nivel 4: treinta
Nivel 4: cinco
Nivel 4: vingt
Nivel 4: trois
Nivel 5: varon
Nivel 5: sangre
```

**Ejemplo de acceso directo a los datos que se trataba de acceder en la pregunta:**

```
var_dump($data['o']);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($data['t']);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($data['t']['treintaycinco']);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($data['t']['treintaycinco'][1][2]['rojo']);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($data['t']['treintaycinco'][1][2]['azul']);
echo '<br>';
```

Esto último es para tratar de que comprendas la estructura del **array** que estás manejando y como la manera en la que tratabas de acceder a los datos no alcanzaba lo que buscabas.